# Approximation of the energy for low $T$ in the early universe

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, big-bang

In Perkins `Particle Physics', to compute the baryon-antibaryon-ratio, he uses that for $Mc^2\gg kT$:
$$E= Mc^2 + \frac{p^2c^2}{2m}.$$
I realize that the approximation comes from $E^2=M^2c^4 + p^2c^2$ and that it is perfectly allright in the ground of the dimension...

But how can one derive this approximation?

(This is example 6.1 p. 149)

Comment: In fact, it is NOT alright dimensionally. Your second term doesn't make sense (units of [E][v]^2 instead of [E]), but it's not a huge problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start from the (special) relativistic expression for energy:
$$E=\sqrt{m^2c^4+p^2c^2}$$
Now, if the first term is much larger than the second ($mc^2\gg kT$ or $v\ll c$), we should take this first term out of the square root and taylor expand the (then in standard form) rest, discarding all but the leading term:
$$E=mc^2\sqrt{1+\frac{p^2c^2}{m^2c^4}}\approx mc^2\Biggl(1+\frac{p^2}{2m^2c^2}\Biggr)=mc^2+\frac{p^2}{2m}$$
This actually reveals a mistake in OP's question: the second term is different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this result only holds for $v\ll c$. Having assumed this, lets start:
$$Total Energy = Rest Energy + Kinetic Energy$$
Keep in mind that since $v\ll c$, $c^2$ is the energy to mass conversion ratio and $K.E.=\frac{p^2}{2m}$
$$E=Mc^2+\frac{p^2}{2m}$$
There!

Comment: Wrong answer, because the units are off.

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually answer the question, which is to *show* why that is the case. You have merely restated OP's question.

Comment: @Danu There, changed it. I don't know why, I just assumed the OP was correct.